# How do I set my email name in postfix?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

**Environment:** CentOS, Postfix and Dovecot.

**Question:** How do I set my email name in postfix?

**Example:** dave@example.com might be the email address but the name would be "El Presidente".

When I open vmailbox I don't see a place to add a name.
`/etc/postfix/vmailbox`

```
test@example.com     email/test@example.com
```

The name that shows up in gmail in front of the subject is automatically "test".

Where might I add a name?

Comment: this question seems to be to have moved to superuser as it does not been having any business related issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a *message transfer agent* (MTA), Postfix doesn't much care about the real name set in the `From:` header. That's typically set in the *mail user agent* (MUA), instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
In main.cf:

myorigin = $mydomain
```